# Key error when converting Data Frame to Dictionary with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dataframe to a dictionary that I can store as a JSON blob in my DB. My code is as follows:

```
import json
from yahooquery import Ticker

ticker_collection = ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'NIO']

for ticker in ticker_collection:
  ticker = Ticker(ticker)
  stock_history = ticker.history(period='ytd', interval='1d')

  dictionary = {
    n: grp.loc[n].to_dict('index')
    for n, grp in stock_history.set_index(['symbol', 'date']).groupby(level='date')
    }
  
  print("\n" * 5)
  print (json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))
```

However this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\git\XXXXX\XXXXX\_4DDE_historical.py", line 23, in <module>
    for n, grp in stock_history.set_index(['symbol', 'date']).groupby(level='date')
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4724, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['symbol', 'date'] are in the columns"
```

But the data frame does containe these columns:

```
                         open     volume        high       close         low    adjclose  dividends
symbol date
AAPL   2021-01-04  133.520004  143301900  133.610001  129.410004  126.760002  129.216919      0.000
       2021-01-05  128.889999   97664900  131.740005  131.009995  128.429993  130.814514      0.000
       2021-01-06  127.720001  155088000  131.050003  126.599998  126.379997  126.411102      0.000
       2021-01-07  128.360001  109578200  131.630005  130.919998  127.860001  130.724655      0.000
       2021-01-08  132.429993  105158200  132.630005  132.050003  130.229996  131.852966      0.000
       2021-01-11  129.190002  100620900  130.169998  128.979996  128.500000  128.787552      0.000
       2021-01-12  128.500000   91951100  129.690002  128.800003  126.860001  128.607819      0.000
       2021-01-13  128.759995   88636800  131.449997  130.889999  128.490005  130.694702      0.000
       2021-01-14  130.800003   90221800  131.000000  128.910004  128.759995  128.717667      0.000
       2021-01-15  128.779999  111598500  130.220001  127.139999  127.000000  126.950294      0.000
       2021-01-19  127.779999   90757300  128.710007  127.830002  126.940002  127.639267      0.000
       2021-01-20  128.660004  104319500  132.490005  132.029999  128.550003  131.832993      0.000
       2021-01-21  133.800003  120529500  139.669998  136.869995  133.589996  136.665771      0.000
       2021-01-22  136.279999  114459400  139.850006  139.070007  135.020004  138.862503      0.000
       2021-01-25  143.070007  157611700  145.089996  142.919998  136.539993  142.706757      0.000
       2021-01-26  143.600006   98390600  144.300003  143.160004  141.369995  142.946396      0.000
       2021-01-27  143.429993  140843800  144.300003  142.059998  140.410004  141.848038      0.000
       2021-01-28  139.520004  142621100  141.990005  137.089996  136.699997  136.885452      0.000
       2021-01-29  135.830002  177180600  136.740005  131.960007  130.210007  131.763107      0.000
       2021-02-01  133.750000  106239800  135.380005  134.139999  130.929993  133.939850      0.000
       2021-02-02  135.729996   83305400  136.309998  134.990005  134.610001  134.788589      0.000
       2021-02-03  135.759995   89880900  135.770004  133.940002  133.610001  133.740158      0.000
       2021-02-04  136.300003   84183100  137.399994  137.389999  134.589996  137.184998      0.000
       2021-02-05  137.350006   75524000  137.419998  136.759995  135.860001  136.759995      0.205
       2021-02-08  136.029999   71297200  136.960007  136.910004  134.919998  136.910004      0.000
       2021-02-09  136.619995   76774200  137.880005  136.009995  135.850006  136.009995      0.000
       2021-02-10  136.479996   73046600  136.990005  135.389999  134.399994  135.389999      0.000
       2021-02-11  135.899994   64154400  136.389999  135.130005  133.770004  135.130005      0.000
       2021-02-12  134.350006   60029300  135.529999  135.369995  133.690002  135.369995      0.000
       2021-02-16  135.490005   80206200  136.009995  133.190002  132.789993  133.190002      0.000
       2021-02-17  131.250000   97918500  132.220001  130.839996  129.470001  130.839996      0.000






                         high        open    volume       close         low    adjclose
symbol date
TSLA   2021-01-04  744.489990  719.460022  48638200  729.770020  717.190002  729.770020
       2021-01-05  740.840027  723.659973  32245200  735.109985  719.200012  735.109985
       2021-01-06  774.000000  758.489990  44700000  755.979980  749.099976  755.979980
       2021-01-07  816.989990  777.630005  51498900  816.039978  775.200012  816.039978
       2021-01-08  884.489990  856.000000  75055500  880.020020  838.390015  880.020020
       2021-01-11  854.429993  849.400024  59554100  811.190002  803.619995  811.190002
       2021-01-12  868.000000  831.000000  46270700  849.440002  827.340027  849.440002
       2021-01-13  860.469971  852.760010  33312500  854.409973  832.000000  854.409973
       2021-01-14  863.000000  843.390015  31266300  845.000000  838.750000  845.000000
       2021-01-15  859.900024  852.000000  38777600  826.159973  819.099976  826.159973
       2021-01-19  850.000000  837.799988  25367000  844.549988  833.000000  844.549988
       2021-01-20  859.500000  858.739990  25665900  850.450012  837.280029  850.450012
       2021-01-21  855.719971  855.000000  20598100  844.989990  841.419983  844.989990
       2021-01-22  848.000000  834.309998  20066500  846.640015  828.619995  846.640015
       2021-01-25  900.400024  855.000000  41173400  880.799988  838.820007  880.799988
       2021-01-26  895.900024  891.380005  23131600  883.090027  871.599976  883.090027
       2021-01-27  891.500000  870.349976  27334000  864.159973  858.659973  864.159973
       2021-01-28  848.000000  820.000000  26378000  835.429993  801.000000  835.429993
       2021-01-29  842.409973  830.000000  34990800  793.530029  780.099976  793.530029
       2021-02-01  842.000000  814.289978  25391400  839.809998  795.559998  839.809998
       2021-02-02  880.500000  844.679993  24346200  872.789978  842.200012  872.789978
       2021-02-03  878.080017  877.020020  18343500  854.690002  853.059998  854.690002
       2021-02-04  856.500000  855.000000  15812700  849.989990  833.419983  849.989990
       2021-02-05  864.770020  845.000000  18524800  852.229980  838.969971  852.229980
       2021-02-08  877.770020  869.669983  20161700  863.419983  854.750000  863.419983
       2021-02-09  859.799988  855.119995  15157700  849.460022  841.750000  849.460022
       2021-02-10  844.820007  843.640015  36216100  804.820007  800.020020  804.820007
       2021-02-11  829.880005  812.440002  21580700  811.659973  801.729980  811.659973
       2021-02-12  817.330017  801.260010  23701700  816.119995  785.330017  816.119995
       2021-02-16  821.000000  818.000000  19686700  796.219971  792.440002  796.219971
       2021-02-17  799.840027  779.090027  25996500  798.150024  762.010010  798.150024






                        high       open     volume      close        low   adjclose
symbol date
NIO    2021-01-04  54.450001  51.200001  213109700  53.490002  50.669998  53.490002
       2021-01-05  53.750000  51.970001  147474800  53.200001  50.400002  53.200001
       2021-01-06  55.279999  54.020000  176397700  50.500000  49.080002  50.500000
       2021-01-07  54.610001  53.049999  119429200  54.279999  52.349998  54.279999
       2021-01-08  59.310001  57.759998  218512800  58.919998  55.880001  58.919998
       2021-01-11  66.989998  64.949997  279770300  62.700001  62.189999  62.700001
       2021-01-12  64.129997  61.419998  184854200  62.040001  60.419998  62.040001
       2021-01-13  64.410004  62.939999  116059200  62.150002  61.410000  62.150002
       2021-01-14  63.230000  62.630001   99338400  60.869999  60.040001  60.869999
       2021-01-15  60.220001  59.840000  132247900  56.270000  55.669998  56.270000
       2021-01-19  59.009998  58.209999   99561100  58.439999  56.410000  58.439999
       2021-01-20  60.090000  59.849998   94983600  57.709999  56.189999  57.709999
       2021-01-21  58.580002  57.020000   73119500  58.340000  55.880001  58.340000
       2021-01-22  62.169998  58.950001  133918100  61.950001  58.320000  61.950001
       2021-01-25  64.519997  64.050003  111986400  59.990002  58.349998  59.990002
       2021-01-26  60.669998  60.040001   70393300  60.310001  58.639999  60.310001
       2021-01-27  59.790001  57.950001   73078300  57.150002  56.599998  57.150002
       2021-01-28  59.459999  56.759998   73955100  58.369999  55.150002  58.369999
       2021-01-29  60.709999  59.029999   78678200  57.000000  56.439999  57.000000
       2021-02-01  59.119999  59.070000   79878700  56.990002  54.369999  56.990002
       2021-02-02  57.540001  57.060001   66234100  55.770000  54.509998  55.770000
       2021-02-03  58.720001  55.959999   80122300  57.980000  54.840000  57.980000
       2021-02-04  59.200001  58.790001   48667900  57.599998  57.110001  57.599998
       2021-02-05  57.980000  57.740002   42892500  56.669998  56.009998  56.669998
       2021-02-08  59.520000  57.080002   64030100  59.070000  56.180000  59.070000
       2021-02-09  63.099998  58.950001   97246500  62.840000  58.240002  62.840000
       2021-02-10  64.599998  62.549999   90366700  61.259998  60.330002  61.259998
       2021-02-11  63.060001  61.689999   55615500  60.270000  59.810001  60.270000
       2021-02-12  61.049999  60.259998   39973800  59.849998  59.099998  59.849998
       2021-02-16  62.139999  60.400002   54914800  59.230000  58.650002  59.230000
       2021-02-17  58.029999  57.919998   63971200  57.320000  55.900002  57.320000
```

I have asked a question previous to this about getting a dataframe into a dictionary format and as I progress through documentation these are the issues I am facing.

The outcome I am after is something like this:

```
{
    "APPL": {
        "2021-01-04": {
            "open" : "133.520004",
            "adjclose" : "133.520004",
            "low" : "133.520004",
            "high" : "133.520004"
        },
        "2021-01-05": {
            "open" : "133.520004",
            "adjclose" : "133.520004",
            "low" : "133.520004",
            "high" : "133.520004"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

symbol/date look already index, so set_index would fail. You should not need that. You could have break down the long function chain to debug which step was problematic.

Comment: I see, I am still unsure what to do here though. I have tried a number of things and followed a number of articles but I cannot seem to get the symbols to be the parent nested dictionary key and the dates listed with all the other data. If the data frame already has those indexes how to I reflect that into the dictionary?